# Using realm for iOS app dev, is there a way to see your database as a GUI?

Tags: ios, swift, database, realm

It would help alot for development.

Comment: realm browser can help you 
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/realm-browser/id1007457278?mt=12

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can

1. Install Realm-browser.
2. Set breakpoint and use lldb console for find db file path

**Objective-C**

```
po [RLMRealmConfiguration defaultConfiguration]
```

**Swift**

```
po RLMRealmConfiguration.defaultConfiguration()
```

[image]

3. Open terminal and type **open** *[Pasted path here]*

Answer (score 0):

You can also set up the Realm Object Server (https://realm.io/products/realm-mobile-platform/) and open the Realms via that. Then you will be able to open the Realms remotely with the Realm Browser and inspect them live, even while the app is running on on the device.